# gradient descent method with linear exact search we have $\nabla^t f(x^k)\nabla f(x^{k+1})=0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

> Prove that in the gradient descent method with linear exact search we
>   have $\nabla^t f(x^k)\nabla f(x^{k+1})=0$

We know that $x^{k+1}$ is obtained by $x^{k+1} = x^k + \alpha_k \nabla f(x^k)$, for some $0<\alpha_k$ that minimizes $f(x^k + \alpha_k \nabla f(x^k))$

I don't see why they should be orthogonal at all. Did I understand something wrong?

Comment: nice question +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's write down the equations at iterations $k+1$ and $k+2$
$$x^{k+1} = x^k + \alpha_k \nabla f(x^k)$$
and
$$x^{k+2} = x^{k+1} + \alpha_{k+1} \nabla f(x^{k+1})$$
Notice that 
$$(x^{k+1}-x^k)^T(x^{k+2}-x^{k+1}) = \alpha_{k}\alpha_{k+1}\nabla f^T(x^k)\nabla f(x^{k+1})$$
Recall that $\alpha_k$ minimizes the following
$$\alpha_k = \operatorname{argmin}_{\alpha} \Phi(\alpha)$$
where 
$$\Phi(\alpha) = f(x_k - \alpha \nabla f(x_k) )$$
i.e. we must have
$$\frac{d \Phi(\alpha_k)}{d \alpha} = 0$$
Using chain rule, we can say that 
$$\frac{d \Phi(\alpha)}{d \alpha}(\alpha_k) = -\nabla f^T(x_k) \nabla f(x^k - \alpha \nabla f(x^k) ) = 0$$
which is 
$$\frac{d \Phi(\alpha)}{d \alpha}(\alpha_k) = -\nabla f^T(x^k) \nabla f(x^{k+1}) = 0$$
and the proof is done.

> This tells you that you will "converge" in a zig-zag fashion to your solution, i.e. each step towards a solution $k+1$, is orthogonal to the next step $k+2$. Pretty cool huh ?